# Magento 2 Customer name always “guest” for PayPal Express/User name not save

Tags: magento2, email

When I get an order from PayPal Express the customer name in the confirmation mail is always "Guest". I checked the mail template and there it says `<p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$order_data.customer_name}}</p>`.

I checked to Database table "sales_order" and found that when a guest user places an order using PayPal at that time customer_firstname and customer_last etc are empty. so when bellowing code call at that time customer field are empty so it printing "Guest".

at Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender.php

```
    protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
        {
            $transport = [
                'order' => $order,
                'order_id' => $order->getId(),
                'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
                'store' => $order->getStore(),
                'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
                'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
                'created_at_formatted' => $order->getCreatedAtFormatted(2),
                'order_data' => [
                    'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
                    'is_not_virtual' => $order->getIsNotVirtual(),
                    'email_customer_note' => $order->getEmailCustomerNote(),
                    'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel()
                ]
            ];
            $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);
    
            /**
             * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
             */
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'email_order_set_template_vars_before',
                ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject, 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
            );
    
            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());
    
            parent::prepareTemplate($order);
        }

Magento\Sales\Model\Order.php
    /**
         * Get customer name
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCustomerName()
        {
            if (null === $this->getCustomerFirstname()) {
                return (string)__('Guest');
            }
    
            $customerName = '';
            if ($this->isVisibleCustomerPrefix() && strlen($this->getCustomerPrefix())) {
                $customerName .= $this->getCustomerPrefix() . ' ';
            }
            $customerName .= $this->getCustomerFirstname();
            if ($this->isVisibleCustomerMiddlename() && strlen($this->getCustomerMiddlename())) {
                $customerName .= ' ' . $this->getCustomerMiddlename();
            }
            $customerName .= ' ' . $this->getCustomerLastname();
            if ($this->isVisibleCustomerSuffix() && strlen($this->getCustomerSuffix())) {
                $customerName .= ' ' . $this->getCustomerSuffix();
            }
    
            return $customerName;
        }
```

I am using Magento 2.4.2 version. this issue only with the PayPal method same things is working fine with another payment method.

Any possible solution?

Comment: Hey, same issue here. Do you use an extension for checkout (onestepcheckout or similar)?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I have the same problem in magento 2.3.5, any solution?

Comment: No.............

Comment: Have you tried using PHP 8.1? It is recommended here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35866

Comment: I've got the same issue on 2.4.4 :( any clue how to fix it ?

Comment: This is a bug in 2.4.4 and should be fixed in 2.4.5 see the github issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to overwrite the core file (which is generally NOT recommended) from the module-paypal. This worked for me:

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php

At the end of the file (around line 1158) update function:

```
protected function prepareGuestQuote() {
$quote = $this->_quote;
$quote->setCustomerId(null)
->setCustomerFirstname($quote->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname())
->setCustomerLastname($quote->getBillingAddress()->getLastname())
->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())
->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
->setCustomerGroupId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Paypal not saving firstname and lastname in the order table so You can get name from the billing address.

```
<p class="greeting">{{trans "%firstname %lastname," firstname=$billing.getFirstname() lastname=$billing.getLastname()}}</p>
```