# Customer name not displayed in confirmation mail in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, customer, transactional-mail

After updating to Magento 2.4.4 the customer name is not displayed in my confirmation mail. I tried all variations I could find:

```
{{var customer.firstname}}
{{trans "%customer_name " customer_name=$order.getShippingAddress().getFirstName()}}
{{trans "%customer_name " customer_name=$order.getBillingAddress().getFirstName()}}
{{trans "Hello %customer_name," customer_name=$customer.name}}
```

Nothing works. Was there a change in 2.4.x?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: do you have any customization for this template in admin or any html file to override the email template ?

Comment: The solution for email https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/340331/magento-2-customer-name-always-guest-for-paypal-express-user-name-not-save/364861#364861